# live streaming from webcam without using Adobe live media encoder

Tags: adobe, media, live, webcam

right now i m using adobe live media encoder to stream live webcam video to the adobe flash media server. All i want to know is that is there a way to stream video to Adobe flash media server from inside a web page using some flash or flex code or some sort of plugin. I dont want the user to use a software installed on his machine ( like the live media encoder) to stream his webcam feed.
I want my website to do it.

So, is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do with Adobe [RTMFP](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=rtmfp&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/rtmfp_faq/&ei=6qchT9bmIYHQrQfX142hCA&usg=AFQjCNEKpPCVbChNfnZCrRzkuGPExKN-xQ&cad=rja) / [RTMP](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=rtmp&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEoQFjAC&url=http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html&ei=5achT5ykBcHPrQeEwaGlCA&usg=AFQjCNFT3XgVdvMeDxizNvXGEqnc74X7VQ&cad=rja) protocols.

RTMFP is a peer-2-peer protocol , where you won't be able to record webcam stream as you did with Adobe Live Media Encoder (which used RTMP)

Just go through these protocols and you will be able to achieve to do this on your website.